# Interesting error based on automatic semicolon insertion JS rules. Explanation required

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, syntax

Today I wrote code for some programming contest. When I run it I was surprised because of error. **Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined** in a place where looks like "error free space".

```
sum = 0
            [-1,0,1].forEach(deltar =>{...});
```

When I add semicolon after `sum` variable value assignment code start to works.

```
sum = 0;
            [-1,0,1].forEach(deltar =>{...});
```

It's very curious about *JS* behavior what do interpreter mismatch here?  how do *JS* mess with *integer* and *array* after it?

Here it is a full code of the function to make the complete picture of variables declaration.

```
function boxBlur(img) {
    let [h,w] = [img.length-1,img[0].length-1];
    let [answer,sum,tmp] = [[],0,[]]
    for(let row = 1; row < h; row += 1){
        tmp = []
        for(let clmn = 1; clmn < w; clmn += 1){
            sum = 0;
            [-1,0,1].forEach(deltar =>{
                [-1,0,1].forEach(deltac =>{
                    sum += img[row+deltar][clmn+deltac]
                });
            });
            tmp.push(parseInt(sum/9));
        }
        answer.push(tmp);
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1,2,3 === 3
```

[comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

so

```
[1,2,3] -> [3] i.e. is property named 3
```

[bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation)

therefore

```
sum = 0[3] is undefined -
```

since the Number(0) has no property called 3

to illustrate further

```js
var sum = 0
[1,2,3,'constructor']

console.log(sum);
```

now the code is equivalent to

```
var sum = 0['constructor']
```

or

```
var sum = 0..constructor
```

which, as you see in the console is the `Number` object constructor

Comment: Is there only one dot at the `var sum = 0.constructor`?

Comment: nope ... properties of integer Number's are accessed using `..` ... see [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation) documentation

Comment: @DmitryDmitriev Or put `()` around them. Or put a whitespace before `.`. `0 .constructor` or `(0).constructor`

Comment: all very interesting but not important :p

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you don't put a semi-colon it doesn't automatically put `;` instead

- it tries to get the property `3` of a number.
- Here `[1,2,3]` doesnot work as array but as [Bracket Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation).
- Due to [Comma Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) the last operand `3`.
- So the `0[3]` is `undefined`.`undefined.forEach(){...}` will obviously throw error.

```js
let sum = 0
[1,2,3]
console.log(sum)
```